# I cannnot connect to guest os(protostar) through ssh from host-pc (linux mint)

Tags: ssh, networking, virtualbox

I'm trying to connect a to guest machine (protostar) through ssh from my host PC (Linux Mint). I'm using VirtualBox.

I tried:

- setting up hostonlyadapters.
- setting up NAT Networking.
- portforwarding(from confing)
- arp-scan

  ```
  me@pc ~ $ ifconfig
  eth0      Link encap:ethernet  hardware-address YY:YY:YY:YY:YY:YY
            UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  metric:1
            RX-packet:0 error:0 loss:0 overrun:0 frame:0
            TX-packet:0 errro:0 loss:0 overrun:0 carrier:0
            Collisions:0 :1000 
            RX-byte:0 (0.0 B)  tx-byte:0 (0.0 B)
            interrupt:20 memory:f7300000-f7320000

  lo        Link encap:local loopback
            inet-address:127.0.0.1  mask:255.0.0.0
            UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  metric:1
  tun0      for VPN
  wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet Hardware-address XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
            inet-address:192.168.11.X  broadcast:192.168.11.255
            masc:255.255.255.0
            UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500 metric:1
            RX-packet:764076 error:0 loss:0 overrun:0 frame:0
            TX-packet:729687 error:0 loss:0 overrun:0 carrier:0
            (Collisions):0 TX:1000 
            RXバイト:895582674 (895.5 MB)  TX-byte:4283r48742 (428.3 MB)
  ```

anyone help?

Comment: Is the guest operating system also Linux Mint or is it something else?

Comment: guest is protostar,which is virtual-machine realesed by exploit-excercies.  it looks like old linux.

Answer (score 1):

Setting the parameters in network as Host-only Adapter, Allow-all and Cable Connected as seen in image below.

[image]

After that I need to power off the machine and starting it again. I did `ip a` to obtain the IP address. I am on Windows and using Putty to connect. Using the IP address and port 22 I am able to ssh into Protostar VM image.